# Toggle buffer-local variables on all visible buffers

Tags: buffers

How can I get the buffers that are currently visible so that I can access them later. I could possibly store them in a list or an alist.

I would like to disable the display of the mode-line for all visible buffers, and toggle them back to their original settings.

This is what I currently have, an implementation that can only handle the current buffer.

```
(defvar-local ramona-mode-line nil
  "Switch for mode-line display.")

(defun ramona-mode-line-toggle ()
  "Turns the mode-line display on or off."

  (interactive)

  (if ramona-mode-line

      (setq mode-line-format ramona-mode-line
            ramona-mode-line nil)

    (setq ramona-mode-line mode-line-format
          mode-line-format nil)

  (force-mode-line-update t))
```

Comment: Unclear. What prevents you from "getting" them later normally, e.g., `C-x b` or `with-current-buffer`? What do you mean by "later"? Same Emacs session? Are you looking for persistence? If so, what kind - re-create the buffer in a new session, or save its state in a file? The question is just far too unclear.

Comment: I want to remove the mode-line of each visible buffer, and be able to toggle them back.

Comment: If you are switching between no mode line and the 'default mode line value', then storing the buffers seems a bit 'superfluous' to me. Anyway, you can get the current visible buffers using `(mapcar #'window-buffer (window-list))`.

Comment: I would be switching between no `mode-line` and the actual one.  So not really switching to the default.  Let us suppose that storing the buffers is `superfluous`, what would be your strategy for switching between normal operation and no mode-line operation on all currently visible buffers?

Comment: Storing is superfluous if you would always toggle between 'no' and  some 'global default' mode-line. Ohterwise, I would probably store the buffer its mode-line format in some 'buffer local default mode-line value' (but an alist would also work of course).

Comment: What `global-value` mode-line are you talking about?  Can you give an example to see if we are missing anything crucial?

Comment: `(default-value 'mode-line-format)`

Comment: That is the problem I am talking about.  Although you could use `default-value`, the buffer might have a local value set up.  I have to get the actual buffer local value rather than the default.

Comment: Didn't @Drew point you to `buffer-local-value` over at `gnu.emacs.help`?

Comment: Yes.  But I need to handle all visible buffers when I am using multiple windows.  I am quite convinced of the requirement to store the `mode-line-format` variable for all visible buffers so I can toggle them.  Is this correct?